# Forecasting of yearly data

Tags: python-3.x, data-mining, data-science, data-analysis, forecasting

My data consists of yearly values (of literacy rates). I am confused on which forecasting method to be used for yearly data. 
The image of data is in the link.

[image]

Please suggest a method for forecasting of literacy rate in 2021 to be implemented in coding.

Answer (score 0):

A hard to beat predictor will be:

Same literacy as last year.

Comment: How can we implement in python?

Comment: Trivial `return y[-1]`

Comment: The literacy rate has to be forecasted for the year 2021. Please suggest a proper method to implement this in coding.

Comment: Forecast `y[-1]` for each year.

Comment: Sorry, can u eleborate on this. I didnt understand.